# How to change a perforce user to superuser

Tags: perforce

How do I change a standard perforce user to a super user? Seen lots of questions on what to do if the super user password is lost but none on how to create another super user, or give a current user super user permissions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to update the Perforce Protections table for that user.

For example:

write user jen * //...

becomes:

super user jen * //...

More information about Perforce Protections is here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.protections.html

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: Thanks. That was it, as simple as that!