# In Perforce, how do I change a regular user into a super user?

Tags: perforce

This thread points to a webpage that no longer exists:  [How to change a perforce user to superuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090757/how-to-change-a-perforce-user-to-superuser/61543039)

How do I change the Perforce Protections Table?

Answer (score 2):

Run `p4 protect`, and add a line like:

```
    super user joe-bob * //...
```

Each protection entry has five parts:

1. the access level (`super`)
2. whether the entry is for a `user` or a `group`
3. the name of the user/group (`joe-bob`)
4. the client IP range this entry applies to (usually `*` for "everywhere")
5. the depot path this entry applies to (there's no point in restricting `super` access to a narrow path since they have permission to edit the protection table themselves anyway, so for `super` entries this is almost always `//...`).

Comment: When I run p4 protect, I get: "You don't have permission for this operation."  and running super gives: " 'super' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: You need to yourself be a super user in order to run `p4 protect` and make another user a super user.  Otherwise anyone could just hijack the entire server at any time.  :)  Contact your Perforce administrator and see if they'll grant you `super` access to be able to perform admin duties.

Comment: We use Assembla as our Perforce administrator.  I set up the entire project with them, so I'm not sure why they didn't make me a super.  Will have to ask them I guess.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Assembla hosting works, but if they give you shell access to the server machine, the easy way to reset the permissions (giving everyone admin rights) is to delete the `db.protect` file from the server root.

Comment: I can't help thinking we didn't need them in the first place... next time I'll investigate setting up our own Perforce server, assuming that is possible.